# Is it possible to have a dictionary with a mutable array as the value in Swift

Tags: dictionary, swift

I am trying to do this:

```
var dictArray = [String:[String]]()
dictArray["test"] = [String]()
dictArray["test"]! += "hello"
```

But I am getting the weird error `NSString is not a subtype of 'DictionaryIndex<String, [(String)]>'`.

I just want to be able to add objects to an array inside a dictionary.

**Update:** Looks like Apple considers this a "known issue" in Swift, implying it will work as expected *eventually*. From the Xcode 6 Beta 4 release notes:

> ...Similarly, you cannot modify the underlying value of a mutable
>   optional value, either  conditionally or within a force-unwrap:
>
> ```
> tableView.sortDescriptors! += NSSortDescriptor(key: "creditName", ascending: true)
> ```
>
> Workaround: Test the optional value explicitly and then assign the
>   result back:
>
> ```
> if let window = NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainWindow {
>     window.title = "Currently experiencing problems"
> }
> tableView.sortDescriptors = tableView.sortDescriptors!
> ```

Comment: Still not working as of Xcode 7.2?

Comment: [SE-171](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0171-reduce-with-inout.md) solves a similar issue for `reduce`. Maybe we'll see `forEach` or `map` with function paramters that have `inout` parameters in the future!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only do this

```
var dictArray = [String:[String]]()
dictArray["test"] = [String]()
var arr = dictArray["test"]!;
arr += "hello"
dictArray["test"] = arr
```

because `dictArray["test"]` give you `Optional<[String]>` which is immutable

```
  6> var test : [String]? = [String]()
test: [String]? = 0 values
  7> test += "hello"
<REPL>:7:1: error: '[String]?' is not identical to 'UInt8'
```

---

`append` also won't work due to the same reason, `Optional` is immutable

```
  3> dictArray["test"]!.append("hello")
<REPL>:3:18: error: '(String, [(String)])' does not have a member named 'append'
dictArray["test"]!.append("hello")
                 ^ ~~~~~~
```

BTW the error message is horrible...

Comment: this is killing me slowly

Comment: To be clear: this does not update the stored value, but updates it with an updated copy.

Answer (score 3):

You may use NSMutableArray instead of [String] as a value type for your dictionary:

```
var dictArray: [String: NSMutableArray] = [:]
dictArray["test"] = NSMutableArray()
dictArray["test"]!.addObject("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in Swift 3. At least I was able to create method that can handle it for you.

```
func appendOrCreate(newValue: Any, toArrayAt key: String, in existingDictionary: inout [AnyHashable:Any]) {

    var mutableArray = [Any]()

    if let array = existingDictionary[key] as? [Any]{
        //include existing values in mutableArray before adding new value
        for existingValue in array {
            mutableArray.append(existingValue)
        }
    }

    //append new value
    mutableArray.append(newValue)

    //save updated array in original dictionary
    existingDictionary[key] = mutableArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that we want class semantics here but have to use structs. If you put class objects into the dictionary, you get what you want!

So, if you *have*¹ to have mutable values, you can wrap them in a class and perform updates with a closure:

```
class MutableWrapper<T> {
    var rawValue: T

    init(_ val: T) {
        self.rawValue = val
    }

    func update(_ with: (inout T) -> Void) {
        with(&self.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
func foo() {
    var dict = [String: MutableWrapper<[String]>]()

    dict["bar"] = MutableWrapper(["rum"])
    dict["bar"]?.update({$0.append("gin")})

    print(dict["bar"]!.rawValue)
    // > ["rum", "gin"]
}
```

---

For what it's worth, I do not see a way to keep caller and wrapper in sync. Even if we declare `init(_ val: inout T)` we will end up with a copy in `rawValue`.

---

1. Performance is not necessarily an issue since the compiler optimizes structs heavily. I'd benchmark any mutable solution against what looks like lots of copy-updates in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 4.1 you can [provide a default value to the subscript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript) which allows you to solve this quite naturally now:

```
dictArray["test", default: []].append("hello")
```