# How to create and add values to Dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I want to create a Dictionary in swift with different type of data(array, string,dictionary)I am able to insert new data to a key but having difficulty in appending more values to them 
here is the json for the dictionary

```
{
  "GenInfo": {
    "First Name":"Varun",
    "Last Name":"Naharia",
    "Phone No":"123456789"
  },
  "LangInfo": ["Hindi","English","Urdu","French"],
  "EduInfo": 
    [
      {
        "Collage":"CIITM",
        "Year":"2009",
        "Degree":"BCA"
      },
      {
        "Collage":"Dept. Of Comp. Sci. & Infor. University Of Kota",
        "Year":"2013",
        "Degree":"MCA"
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to add these values to dictionary one by one like first GenInfo, then first language of LangInfo then EduInfo

[image: LangInfo]
Lang Info

[image: EduInfo]
EduInfo

I Used `dict["GenInfo"] = ["FirstName":first,"LastName":last,"Phone":phone]` to add the GenInfo in the dic where first and last is the variable with value.

**EDIT #1**
`var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>()`

Comment: Can you show do you define dict? If you are using `let` to define it the Dictionary will not be mutable. You should use `var` to make that Dictionary mutable.

Comment: yes it is var and I already added GenInfo it but having problem adding array value one by one in LangInfo

Comment: Ok can you post the code where you are trying to append the LangInfo?

Comment: `dict["Language"]=[lang]`

Comment: Is the 'data' property of LangData also defined using 'var'?

Comment: yes I am not getting error while assigning value but the problem is I don't know how to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80100/discussion-between-varun-naharia-and-atreat).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue, apparently not fixed yet (see [Is it possible to have a dictionary with a mutable array as the value in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855228/is-it-possible-to-have-a-dictionary-with-a-mutable-array-as-the-value-in-swift))

The workaround would be to create a new variable with your array and then assign it back:

```
    var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
    dict["GenInfo"] = ["FirstName":"first","LastName":"last","Phone":"phone"]
    dict["Language"] = ["langage1", "langage2"]

    if var languages = dict["Language"] as? [String] {
        languages.append("langage3")
        dict["Language"] = languages
    }
```