# How to append value to Multilevel Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have dictionary in swift

```
var data = ["GenInfo":Dictionary<String,String>(),"LangInfo":Array<String>(),"EduInfo":Array<Dictionary<String,String>>(),"JobInfo":Array<Dictionary<String,String>>(),"SkillInfo":Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()]
```

Now  I want to add values to this dictionary, How can I do that.
Suppose if I want to add these

```
"FirstName": "Varun",
"Email": "varun@gmail.com",
"State": "Rajasthan",
"Address": "Plot No. 00, Bhagwan Nagar 31,",
"Zip": "21354",
"Phone": "123456789",
"LastName": "Sharma"
```

value to the `valueForKey "GenInfo"`

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a String:String dictionary to represent a person as opposed to a Struct or a Class?

Comment: if you have any other way to do this please explain, I just want to add a lot data to dictionary and then want to convert it to json.

Comment: I like using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) to convert to and from JSON.

Comment: Thank you for this question, @VarunNaharia. When I attempted to answer this question it lead to another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766348/why-cant-i-cast-a-value-of-a-mixed-type-dictionary-and-update-the-value) and a deeper understanding of Swift.

Comment: it is very confusing I asked the same question in another way a day before and the answer is very confusing and I got the right answer if asked it the other way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739255/how-to-create-and-add-values-to-dictionary-in-swift , may be both question are different in a way but main motive behind the both question is to make a dictionary dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where making a Dictionary (i.e. NSDictionary) whose not mutable after it's declaration (unlike NSMutableDictionary).

That said, you can either do like this :

```
var data : NSMutableDictionary = ["GenInfo":Dictionary<String,String>(),"LangInfo":Array<String>(),"EduInfo":Array<Dictionary<String,String>>(),"JobInfo":Array<Dictionary<String,String>>(),"SkillInfo":Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()]

data["GenInfo"] = ["FirstName": "Varun",
                 "Email": "varun@gmail.com",
                 "State": "Rajasthan",
                 "Address": "Plot No. 00, Bhagwan Nagar 31,",
                 "Zip": "21354",
                 "Phone": "123456789",
                 "LastName": "Sharma"
                ]

data["LangInfo"] = ["English", "French", "Italian"]

data["EduInfo"]   = [["Degree": "MCA", "School": "University of Kota", "Year": "2013"], ["Degree": "Another degree", "School": "University of London", "Year": "2015"]]

// And so on...
```

Or like this :

```
var data = [String: AnyObject]()

data["GenInfo"]   = [String: String]()   // Dictionary<String,String>()
data["LangInfo"]  = [String]()           // Array<String>()
data["EduInfo"]   = [[String: String]]() // Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()
data["JobInfo"]   = [[String: String]]() // Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()
data["SkillInfo"] = [[String: String]]() // Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()

data["GenInfo"]   = ["FirstName": "Varun",
                     "Email": "varun@gmail.com",
                     "State": "Rajasthan",
                     "Address": "Plot No. 00, Bhagwan Nagar 31,",
                     "Zip": "21354",
                     "Phone": "123456789",
                     "LastName": "Sharma"
                    ]

data["LangInfo"]  = ["English", "French", "Italian"]

data["EduInfo"]   = [["Degree": "MCA", "School": "University of Kota", "Year": "2013"], ["Degree": "Another degree", "School": "University of London", "Year": "2015"]]

// And so on...
```

Comment: what about the third one, the one with a dictionary if data is like  
       ` ("Degree": "MCA",
        "School": "University of Kota",
        "Year": "2013")
      (
      "Degree": "BCA",
        "School": "University of Kota",
        "Year": "2009"
       )
    `

Comment: What about it ? If it's only `[String: String]()` you can do has `data["GenInfo"]`. Otherwise, if it is correctly `[[String: String]]()` see the updated code above (and it will be the same for JobInfo and SkillInfo).

Comment: how did you said that it is not mutable I didn't use the let for data it is var so I think it is mutable correct me if I am wrong

Comment: thanks it explains a lot but still I have question for EduInfo can I make a loop and add one block at time in the `data["EduInfo"]`

Comment: You should at least give it a try before asking (but yes, it should work). Regarding your previous question, if you look at the Apple's documentation you can read that _Swift’s Dictionary type is bridged to Foundation’s NSDictionary class._ That said, if you look at the NSDictionary documentation you can see that it's not mutable (whereas NSMutableDictionary is). Hope it helped you understand.

Comment: @Ichamp I must disagree with you. If you use Swift's built-in Dictionary, which is a struct, it will be mutable when declared with the `var` and immutable when declared with `let`. Notice that the `updateValue:key:` function is declared as mutating. Also the second bit of code above contradicts your assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
var data: NSMutableDictionary = ["GenInfo":Dictionary<String,String>(),"LangInfo":Array<String>(),"EduInfo":Array<Dictionary<String,String>>(),"JobInfo":Array<Dictionary<String,String>>(),"SkillInfo":Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()]


data["GenInfo"] = ["FirstName": "Varun",
    "Email": "varun@gmail.com",
    "State": "Rajasthan",
    "Address": "Plot No. 00, Bhagwan Nagar 31,",
    "Zip": "21354",
    "Phone": "123456789",
    "LastName": "Sharma"
]
```

Comment: is not possible in Dictionary ? that come in exchange of NSDictionary  ?

Comment: `NSDictionary` is not mutable, you can't add objects in it afterwards. You need an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: but NSDictionary is replaced by let Dictionary and NSMutableDictionary is replaced by var Dictionary in swift, what the use of the new swift if use all old method

Comment: Yes but the type that is automatically inferred is `NSDictionary` and that's not mutable. If you Hold the Alt/Option button and click on the `data` variable it will say it's of `NSDictionary` type(`var data: NSDictionary`).

Comment: You can change the type for `data` to `Dictionary<NSObject, NSObject>` and it should work.

Comment: NSObject or AnyObject ? I think NSObject is for objective-c and for Swift it is AnyObject, Yes I know we can use NS in swift but  then what the use of AnyObject

Comment: If you use `AnyObject` you'll get an error because `AnyObject` does not conform conform to `Hashable` protocol which is required for the `struct  Dictionary` (`struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value>`)