# Why can't I cast a value of a mixed type dictionary and update the value?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I was attempting to answer another StackOverflow question and found my knowledge of Swift lacking.

Below is playground code that demonstrates the issue I'm having.

```
import Foundation

// How do I access the value of dictionary and update the value, without replacing it?
// How do I make the inner dictionary mutable?

var sampleDict = [
    "dictionary" : [String: String](),
    "array" : [String]()
]


(sampleDict["dictionary"] as! [String:String]).updateValue("avalue", forKey: "akey")
// ERROR: Swift.playground:12:27: error: immutable value of type '[String : String]' only has mutating members named 'updateValue'
//(sampleDict["dictionary"] as! [String:String]).updateValue("avalue", forKey: "akey")

(sampleDict["dictionary"] as! [String:String])["akey"] = "avalue"
// ERROR: Swift.playground:14:56: error: cannot assign to the result of this expression
// (sampleDict["dictionary"] as! [String:String])["akey"] = "avalue"
```

My questions are

- How do I access the value of a mixedType dictionary and update the value, without replacing it?
- How do I make the inner dictionary mutable?
- Is this simply impossible?

Comment: I think the least ugly way would be to separate sampleDict into two explicitly typed ones. [String: [String: String]] and [String: [String]]. Then you can write sampleDictOne["dictionary"]!["avaule"] = "akey"

Comment: @5hrp thanks for the reply. Need to update my question to clarify that it's about a mixedType dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible. When looking at the `Dictionary` declaration, there seems to be no method to changing a value, only replacing it. It kind of makes sense because when you get a value, it returns a copy of the real struct in the dictionary (structs are always copied). Of course it would work when using a class. That's my theory..

EDIT: I just found out that it does work without the cast to [String: String] and a dictionary with just the right type:

```
var sampleDict = ["dictionary" : [String: String]()]
sampleDict["dictionary"]?.updateValue("avalue", forKey: "akey")
sampleDict["dictionary"]?["akey"] = "avalue"
```

Comment: Yes that will work. But I added that array value to the sampleDict so it was a mixed type dictionary. I should update my question to clarify. It's strange that it doesn't work for a mixed type dictionary.

Comment: @Tobias Yes it was clear from your question, I just wanted to point out that this works ;)