# Immutable value error when appending to array within dictionary after downcasting

Tags: swift

```
var someDict = [String:Any]()
someDict["foo"] = ["hello"]
(someDict["foo"] as? [String])?.append("goodbye") // error here
```

I am trying to add a value to an existing dictionary containing an array. The dictionary also contains other non-array values, so it has to have value type `Any`.  The problem is that, when I do this, I get an error `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[String]'`.  Some Googling turned up a few references such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855228/is-it-possible-to-have-a-dictionary-with-a-mutable-array-as-the-value-in-swift) suggesting that arrays within dictionaries are always immutable, but the compiler doesn't complain if I do this:

```
var someDict = [String:[String]]()
someDict["foo"] = ["hello"]
someDict["foo"]?.append("goodbye")
```

so I suspect that information is outdated and it's something specific to the downcasting.  Is there any way I can get around this without copying and re-assigning the entire dictionary value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is related the the downcasting. Try this instead:

```
var someDict = [String:Any]()
someDict["foo"] = ["hello"]
if var arr = someDict["foo"] as? [String] {
    arr.append("goodbye")
    someDict["foo"] = arr
}
```