# How to use a mutable array as dictionary value in a performant way?

Tags: swift

Is there a way to put mutable arrays as values to Swift dictionaries without performance losses? When I was searching around, most approaches seemed to suggest grabbing the array from the dictionary as a var, adding to it, and then setting it back to the dictionary ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855228/is-it-possible-to-have-a-dictionary-with-a-mutable-array-as-the-value-in-swift)). However, this seems to be very inefficient.

I benchmarked this approach against Objective-C and Swift with NSMutableArrays, and with 1M entries it seems to be 180x slower, and seems to be exhibiting non-linear growth, suggesting that the compiler is not able to sufficiently optimize this, either.

```
import Foundation
 
let startDate = Date()
var dict = [Int:[Int]]()
for i in 0..<1_000_000 {
    let key = i % 7
    var arr = dict[key] ?? [Int]()
    arr.append(i)
    dict[key] = arr
}
print("Time spent: \(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)")
 
// $ swiftc MutableDictionary.swift -o MutableDictionarySwift -framework Foundation -O
// $ ./MutableDictionarySwift
// Time spent: 18.316431999206543
```

Objective-C:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
            NSNumber *key = @(i % 7);
            NSMutableArray *arr = dict[key] ?: [NSMutableArray new];
            [arr addObject:@(i)];
            dict[key] = arr;
        }
        NSLog(@"Number of elements: %lu", dict.count);
        NSLog(@"Time spent: %f", [NSDate date].timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate);
    }
}
 
// $ clang MutableDictionary.m -o MutableDictionaryObjc -framework Foundation -O3
// $ ./MutableDictionaryObjc
// 2020-11-26 17:41:17.686 MutableDictionaryObjc[12012:775366] Number of elements: 7
// 2020-11-26 17:41:17.686 MutableDictionaryObjc[12012:775366] Time spent: 0.098124
```

Swift with NSMutableArray:

```
import Foundation
 
let startDate = Date()
var dict = [Int:NSMutableArray]()
for i in 0..<1_000_000 {
    let key = i % 7
    let arr = dict[key] ?? NSMutableArray()
    arr.add(i)
    dict[key] = arr
}
print("Time spent: \(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)")
 
// $ swiftc MutableDictionary2.swift -o MutableDictionarySwift2 -framework Foundation -O  
// $ ./MutableDictionarySwift2 
// Time spent: 0.10528397560119629
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your `arr` local variable is a second reference to the array (the first being the reference made by the dictionary), so mutating operations require a copy. To get around this, you need to either edit the array in-place, or if you insist on aliasing with a local variable, you should set remove it from the dictionary, then add it back after.

Comment: Makes sense. In-place editing sounds great, but I've seen some situations needing a local variable. In that case, it seems that your other tip works as well: I nilled out the previous dictionary value before setting it, and this fixed the performance problem.

Is it guaranteed that the compiler will not create a copy if I nil out the pre-existing dictionary value?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the compiler. It’s the behaviour of the CoW implementations of the standard library’s data structures, and how they mutate into place on uniquely referenced buffers, but copy non-uniquely referenced buffers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that both Swift array and `NSMutableArray` under the hood kinda do the same things: when they have no more allocated space for new items, they allocate a new buffer. And the new buffer allocation logic should be fairly similar in both Swift and Objective-C.

The problem with your Swift array code, as Alexander pointed out in his comment, is the fact that you create a local copy of the array that is stored into the dictionary. And as soon as you mutate that local array, the copy-on-write mechanism triggers a copy of the array buffer, which results into another heap allocation. And the bigger the array, the more it takes to duplicate the buffer.

The nonlinear growth you see is due to the fact that the array buffer increases don't occur that often, as the array implementations have a pretty good heuristic for the capacity increase, in order to avoid allocations every time a new element is added. However the buffer duplication due to copy-on-write happens at every iteration.

You will get better results with the Swift arrays if you mutate them in place:

```swift
for i in 0..<1_000_000 {
    let key = i % 7
    dict[key, default: [Int]()].append(i)
}
```

Both measurements and Instruments show a dramatically improved performance with the above change, with the Swift code being faster than the Objective-C one.